# sed to replace same patterns that have slightly different ending to the string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am using grep on an entire directory and sed to replace the string. There are some conflicts in replacing the as there are two strings that are very similar and have the same pattern. Only big difference is the file extension at the end.

String1

> xargs sed -i
>   's,//website.net/resources/special.js,//newsite.net/location/newspecial.js,g'

String2

> xargs sed -i
>   's,//website.net/resources/file.swf,//newsite.net/location/player.swf,g'

How do I specify that .js receives the correct replacement and .swf receives the correct replacement?

Answer (score 0):

For the first, you can restrict the match easily, for the second you need a mapping to provide the old file name to new file name otherwise how the script is going to know that "file.swf" to be replaced with "player.swf".

```
$ echo '//website.net/resources/special.js' | 
  sed -r 's,(.*/)(.*.js)$,\1new\2,'

//website.net/resources/newspecial.js
```

first match group will include every char until the last `/`., second match things ending with `.js`, you may need another anchor if there are multiple elements on the same line.  Note that in one element case `g` is unnecessary.